# How to Proguard two android project？

Tags: android, proguard, jsr

I have developed two projects  in Andriod system based on java A and B , the codes  in project  A  rely on codes in project B ,also the codes in project B  rely on codes in project A.Can I use Proguard obfuscate A but not obfuscate B, A and B can also work well?

Comment: I think in the proguard.txt you can exclude packages etc. Im no expert though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent B from being obfuscated include something along the lines of:

```
-keep class com.projectB.package.** { *; }
```

for all the packages in project B.  This goes in your proguard.cfg of any project that uses these files.  When proguard runs, it will know to not obfuscate anything in B and project A will be obfuscated.